# Monitor calibration icm profile vs color settings?

Tags: video, display, colors, calibration

We bought a Dell U2713H monitor, and because of the price tag we thought it deserves a calibration, so I asked for it.

This is the first monitor I bought calibrated, I always thought these are just settings (R, G, B, contrast, brightness...), but in the end we got an .icm profile, for the "Standard" settings of the monitor.

For example at http://www.flatpanelshd.com/review.php?subaction=showfull&id=1347521897 (Search for "Our calibrated settings are") the calibration didn't result in an "ICM profile", but in settings for the monitor.

What is the difference between the 2? What is "better"? Should we have gotten both settings?